# Fragment does not show up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I am new to fragments. I have a `BroadcastReceiver` in my mainactivity where I call from a baseadapter and I use this code to show a fragment but never shows up!

```
 BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Fragment frag = new NewviewFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(frag, "nav_newview");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
           
        }
    };
```

and this is the code from my Fragment

```
    package com.example.myapp.ui.newview;
         public class NewviewFragment extends Fragment {
        
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                         ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    newviewViewModel =
     new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NewviewViewModel.class);
                    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newview, container, false);

            
 newviewViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                        //    textView.setText(s);
                        }
                    });
                    return root;
                }
        
        }
```

and this is my fragment_newview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.newview.NewviewFragment">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Did `onReceive` get called?

Comment: Yep i have checked it, it is called and i get response from fragment in system.out.println!

Comment: Do you have a placeholder in the main layout that you want to host this fragment on?

Comment: What do you mean? I am new to this ... show me an example. There is a navigation fragment  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

Comment: and this layout with a toolbar in mainactivity    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.myapp.PopupOverlay">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

Comment: please show the `mobile_navigation.xml`

Comment: <navigation 
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home"
    ><fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_helloworld"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.ui.helloworld.HelloworldFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_helloworld"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_helloworld" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_newview"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.ui.newview.NewviewFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_newview"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_newview" />
</navigation>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using navigation architecture component library, you should not make fragment transaction manually with `FragmentTransaction`.

You just can make transactions through the `NavController`

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);  // R.id.nav_host_fragment is the id of the placeholder fragment in content_main.xml
        controller.navigate(R.id.nav_newview);           
    }
};
```

I am assuming that your main activity is named as `MainActivity` & the `BroadcastReceiver` is hosted in this activity.

UPDATE:

I didn't notice that you made a fade animation, with navigation components In order to have some animation:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.secondFragment, null, getNavOptions());

NavOptions getNavOptions() {
    return new NavOptions.Builder()
            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.fragment_open_enter)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim)
            .build();
}
```

And create these animation as you like in `res/anim`

You can also do that in mobile_navigation.xml

Comment: No problem! Hope the best to you!

Comment: @stefanosn please check updated answer.. I just didn't notice you used some animation